# Android AsyncTask process (logcat) does not output messages (on emulator)

Tags: android, android-emulator, logcat

The logcat process is launched, I don't get any error or force close. It simply seems to not generate any output.

```js
    String commandLine = "logcat -v time -b main *:V";
    String line;

    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        while(!mStop && (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null && newMessages.size() < maxMessages) {
            // It does not reach this point
            // Debugger shows 
            // mStop == false
            // newMessages.size == 0
            // maxMessages == 5000
            // line == null
```

The suspicion is that logcat exits wihtout printing anything out. I tried this in a command line and it does output logcat messages.

I replaced `logcat` with `ls` and then bufferedReader does fill `line`.

The inspection of `bufferedReader` shows member `in`(InputStreamReader) which itself has a memeber `endOfInput` which is **false** before the readLine() and becomes **true** right after it.

**LAST NEWS:**
I opened the Terminal Emulator within the emulator itself, and run it:

```
$ logcat -v time -b main *:V
Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': Permission denied
$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking for similar post it seems this is quite a **duplicate** from:

[Android unable to run logcat from application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219345/android-unable-to-run-logcat-from-application)

In short, the problem was: a user permission is required to read logs, so I added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```

to the manifest and it works fine now.