# Android Logcat Rotation Size and Number Of Rotation Parameters

Tags: android, logging, android-logcat

Hi Android Developers!

I am trying to figure out what -r and -n parameters for logcat utilitiy mean. When my log file exceeds -r number of kilobytes in size; it deletes the whole content of my log file which leaves it empty or creates a new file to continue with the logging process? What exactly does -n mean as well, ofc?

Thanks for your replies in advance,
Ilker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**-n** specifies the maximum number of rotated logs 
**-r** specifies the size after which the log file should rotate

See http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html for more info.

Comment: What's the `-r` limit?  Apparently it's > the default (16) and less than what I'm specifying (10000).  Clearly I can use binary search to determine it myself, but a doc that contains this would probably be useful to know about (haven't found it yet).

Note that I use -r and -n, and it works for me.  I invoke logCat from my Android app.  A useful reference for the code is this Question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219345/android-unable-to-run-logcat-from-application

Comment: Can you write a command to save logact contents into a file including -r and -n paramaters.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

[Source](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html)

So after a file size reaches the limit specified using `-r` option then new file is created and logs are redirected to that file. Number of such files to be created are specified by `-n` option. When n count is reached your 1st file will be overwritten.