# Android FileObserver - create new file

Tags: java, android, fileobserver

I have to create a file mechanism which creates a new file, check at real time if the file has reached to some length and then open a new file in order to write the extra data. 
But then, if the new file has also reached the same limit, open a new file.

For this, I was thinking to use file observer, but it requires to change the watched file name, and it seems that each file will have a new instance of fileObserver.

is the an easiest way to do it?

Comment: Did find an answer?  I am facing the same question.

Comment: Hi, no.. but you can try with android log rotation, maybe it will help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539519/android-logcat-rotation-size-and-number-of-rotation-parameters